# VBA Offset Match Not Working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a goal seek setting a certain cell equal to zero by changing another cell in Excel with VBA.

The cell I want to set to zero changes location so I need to use a match offset combination I think.

I get a compile error Invalid qualifier when I run the code though. Any ideas?

Thank you.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As Integer
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.match("G3", Range("I6:SF6"), 0).Value

Range("I199").Offset(0, x.Value).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("GN197")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
"G3"
```

with:

```
Range("G3")
```

Comment: As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx, the `Lookup_value` is a `Variant`, so using `"G3"` would be acceptable (albeit not what the OP wants, perhaps).

Comment: @sancho.s  I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using named range instead of using Range reference.  This way even if rows or columns are added you named range is still available.

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx), the return value of `WorksheetFunction.Match` is a `Double`. So you probably do not have `Value` available. Try removing it.

PS: I do not have a system with Excel to test this.

PS2: You did not indicate the line producing the error.